# Not able to see flink custom metrics to Prometheus

Tags: configuration, apache-flink, prometheus, metrics

I have a flink job written in scala and I am creating one custom metric to count the nmber of events in a stream. The job is deployed on kubernetes and I see system metrics of job-manager and task-managers in the prometheus. However, we don't see the custom metrics in prometheus though we see that in Flink UI. Below is the custom metrics code:

```
    val sampleProcessFunction = new ProcessFunction[String, String] {
    @transient private var counter: Counter = _
    override def open(parameters: Configuration): Unit =
      counter = getRuntimeContext.getMetricGroup.addGroup("abc").counter("streamcounter")

    override def processElement(
                                 value: String,
                                 ctx: ProcessFunction[String, String]#Context,
                                 out: Collector[String]): Unit = {
      
        val result = value.parseJson.toString
        counter.inc()
        out.collect(result)
      
    }
}
```

flink-config.yaml has these entries related to prometheus:

```
   taskmanager.network.detailed-metrics: true
   metrics.reporter.prom.class:org.apache.flink.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusReporter
   metrics.reporter.prom.port: 8080
```

Not only custom metrics, any taskmanager metrics that follows the path **taskmanager.job.*** are not exposed in the metrics endpoint. When I am getting into a taskmanager pod and doing a curl to the metrics endpoint like this:

```
kubectl exec -it flink-taskmanager-app-7448cdb787-9c48j -- /bin/bash
curl http://localhost:8080/metrics
```

I am only getting the status metrics related to taskmanager:

```
# HELP flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Mapped_MemoryUsed MemoryUsed (scope: taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Mapped)
# TYPE flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Mapped_MemoryUsed gauge
flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Mapped_MemoryUsed{host="172_26_129_190",tm_id="172_26_129_190:6122_3b582c",} 0.0
# HELP flink_taskmanager_Status_Flink_Memory_Managed_Used Used (scope: taskmanager_Status_Flink_Memory_Managed)
# TYPE flink_taskmanager_Status_Flink_Memory_Managed_Used gauge
flink_taskmanager_Status_Flink_Memory_Managed_Used{host="172_26_129_190",tm_id="172_26_129_190:6122_3b582c",} 0.0
# HELP flink_taskmanager_Status_Shuffle_Netty_UsedMemorySegments UsedMemorySegments (scope: taskmanager_Status_Shuffle_Netty)
# TYPE flink_taskmanager_Status_Shuffle_Netty_UsedMemorySegments gauge
flink_taskmanager_Status_Shuffle_Netty_UsedMemorySegments{host="172_26_129_190",tm_id="172_26_129_190:6122_3b582c",} 0.0
# HELP flink_taskmanager_Status_Network_TotalMemorySegments TotalMemorySegments (scope: taskmanager_Status_Network)
# TYPE flink_taskmanager_Status_Network_TotalMemorySegments gauge
flink_taskmanager_Status_Network_TotalMemorySegments{host="172_26_129_190",tm_id="172_26_129_190:6122_3b582c",} 30037.0
# HELP flink_taskmanager_Status_Shuffle_Netty_AvailableMemory AvailableMemory (scope: taskmanager_Status_Shuffle_Netty)
# TYPE flink_taskmanager_Status_Shuffle_Netty_AvailableMemory gauge
flink_taskmanager_Status_Shuffle_Netty_AvailableMemory{host="172_26_129_190",tm_id="172_26_129_190:6122_3b582c",} 9.84252416E8
# HELP flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_ClassLoader_ClassesLoaded ClassesLoaded (scope: taskmanager_Status_JVM_ClassLoader)
# TYPE flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_ClassLoader_ClassesLoaded gauge
flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_ClassLoader_ClassesLoaded{host="172_26_129_190",tm_id="172_26_129_190:6122_3b582c",} 11075.0
# HELP flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Metaspace_Max Max (scope: taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Metaspace)
# TYPE flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Metaspace_Max gauge
flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Metaspace_Max{host="172_26_129_190",tm_id="172_26_129_190:6122_3b582c",} 2.68435456E8
# HELP flink_taskmanager_Status_Shuffle_Netty_RequestedMemoryUsage RequestedMemoryUsage (scope: taskmanager_Status_Shuffle_Netty)
# TYPE flink_taskmanager_Status_Shuffle_Netty_RequestedMemoryUsage gauge
flink_taskmanager_Status_Shuffle_Netty_RequestedMemoryUsage{host="172_26_129_190",tm_id="172_26_129_190:6122_3b582c",} 0.0
# HELP flink_taskmanager_Status_Shuffle_Netty_AvailableMemorySegments AvailableMemorySegments (scope: taskmanager_Status_Shuffle_Netty)
# TYPE flink_taskmanager_Status_Shuffle_Netty_AvailableMemorySegments gauge
flink_taskmanager_Status_Shuffle_Netty_AvailableMemorySegments{host="172_26_129_190",tm_id="172_26_129_190:6122_3b582c",} 30037.0
# HELP flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Metaspace_Used Used (scope: taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Metaspace)
# TYPE flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Metaspace_Used gauge
flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Metaspace_Used{host="172_26_129_190",tm_id="172_26_129_190:6122_3b582c",} 6.5252976E7
# HELP flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_NonHeap_Max Max (scope: taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_NonHeap)
# TYPE flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_NonHeap_Max gauge
flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_NonHeap_Max{host="172_26_129_190",tm_id="172_26_129_190:6122_3b582c",} 7.80140544E8
# HELP flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Direct_Count Count (scope: taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Direct)
# TYPE flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Direct_Count gauge
flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Direct_Count{host="172_26_129_190",tm_id="172_26_129_190:6122_3b582c",} 30065.0
# HELP flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Direct_TotalCapacity TotalCapacity (scope: taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Direct)
# TYPE flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Direct_TotalCapacity gauge
flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Direct_TotalCapacity{host="172_26_129_190",tm_id="172_26_129_190:6122_3b582c",} 9.85225216E8
# HELP flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_GarbageCollector_G1_Old_Generation_Time Time (scope: taskmanager_Status_JVM_GarbageCollector_G1_Old_Generation)
# TYPE flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_GarbageCollector_G1_Old_Generation_Time gauge
flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_GarbageCollector_G1_Old_Generation_Time{host="172_26_129_190",tm_id="172_26_129_190:6122_3b582c",} 0.0
# HELP flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Threads_Count Count (scope: taskmanager_Status_JVM_Threads)
# TYPE flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Threads_Count gauge
flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Threads_Count{host="172_26_129_190",tm_id="172_26_129_190:6122_3b582c",} 51.0
# HELP flink_taskmanager_Status_Shuffle_Netty_TotalMemory TotalMemory (scope: taskmanager_Status_Shuffle_Netty)
# TYPE flink_taskmanager_Status_Shuffle_Netty_TotalMemory gauge
flink_taskmanager_Status_Shuffle_Netty_TotalMemory{host="172_26_129_190",tm_id="172_26_129_190:6122_3b582c",} 9.84252416E8
# HELP flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_GarbageCollector_G1_Young_Generation_Time Time (scope: taskmanager_Status_JVM_GarbageCollector_G1_Young_Generation)
# TYPE flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_GarbageCollector_G1_Young_Generation_Time gauge
flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_GarbageCollector_G1_Young_Generation_Time{host="172_26_129_190",tm_id="172_26_129_190:6122_3b582c",} 55.0
# HELP flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_ClassLoader_ClassesUnloaded ClassesUnloaded (scope: taskmanager_Status_JVM_ClassLoader)
# TYPE flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_ClassLoader_ClassesUnloaded gauge
flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_ClassLoader_ClassesUnloaded{host="172_26_129_190",tm_id="172_26_129_190:6122_3b582c",} 0.0
# HELP flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Heap_Used Used (scope: taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Heap)
# TYPE flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Heap_Used gauge
flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Heap_Used{host="172_26_129_190",tm_id="172_26_129_190:6122_3b582c",} 1.56297264E8
# HELP flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_CPU_Time Time (scope: taskmanager_Status_JVM_CPU)
# TYPE flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_CPU_Time gauge
flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_CPU_Time{host="172_26_129_190",tm_id="172_26_129_190:6122_3b582c",} 4.001E10
# HELP flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Direct_MemoryUsed MemoryUsed (scope: taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Direct)
# TYPE flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Direct_MemoryUsed gauge
flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Direct_MemoryUsed{host="172_26_129_190",tm_id="172_26_129_190:6122_3b582c",} 9.85225217E8
# HELP flink_taskmanager_Status_Shuffle_Netty_UsedMemory UsedMemory (scope: taskmanager_Status_Shuffle_Netty)
# TYPE flink_taskmanager_Status_Shuffle_Netty_UsedMemory gauge
flink_taskmanager_Status_Shuffle_Netty_UsedMemory{host="172_26_129_190",tm_id="172_26_129_190:6122_3b582c",} 0.0
# HELP flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_GarbageCollector_G1_Young_Generation_Count Count (scope: taskmanager_Status_JVM_GarbageCollector_G1_Young_Generation)
# TYPE flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_GarbageCollector_G1_Young_Generation_Count gauge
flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_GarbageCollector_G1_Young_Generation_Count{host="172_26_129_190",tm_id="172_26_129_190:6122_3b582c",} 3.0
# HELP flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Metaspace_Committed Committed (scope: taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Metaspace)
# TYPE flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Metaspace_Committed gauge
flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Metaspace_Committed{host="172_26_129_190",tm_id="172_26_129_190:6122_3b582c",} 6.7375104E7
# HELP flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Heap_Max Max (scope: taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Heap)
# TYPE flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Heap_Max gauge
flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Heap_Max{host="172_26_129_190",tm_id="172_26_129_190:6122_3b582c",} 4.429185024E9
# HELP flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_NonHeap_Committed Committed (scope: taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_NonHeap)
# TYPE flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_NonHeap_Committed gauge
flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_NonHeap_Committed{host="172_26_129_190",tm_id="172_26_129_190:6122_3b582c",} 9.8787328E7
# HELP flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_NonHeap_Used Used (scope: taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_NonHeap)
# TYPE flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_NonHeap_Used gauge
flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_NonHeap_Used{host="172_26_129_190",tm_id="172_26_129_190:6122_3b582c",} 9.4597576E7
# HELP flink_taskmanager_Status_Shuffle_Netty_TotalMemorySegments TotalMemorySegments (scope: taskmanager_Status_Shuffle_Netty)
# TYPE flink_taskmanager_Status_Shuffle_Netty_TotalMemorySegments gauge
flink_taskmanager_Status_Shuffle_Netty_TotalMemorySegments{host="172_26_129_190",tm_id="172_26_129_190:6122_3b582c",} 30037.0
# HELP flink_taskmanager_Status_Flink_Memory_Managed_Total Total (scope: taskmanager_Status_Flink_Memory_Managed)
# TYPE flink_taskmanager_Status_Flink_Memory_Managed_Total gauge
flink_taskmanager_Status_Flink_Memory_Managed_Total{host="172_26_129_190",tm_id="172_26_129_190:6122_3b582c",} 4.294967296E9
# HELP flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_CPU_Load Load (scope: taskmanager_Status_JVM_CPU)
# TYPE flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_CPU_Load gauge
flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_CPU_Load{host="172_26_129_190",tm_id="172_26_129_190:6122_3b582c",} 0.002796347271376764
# HELP flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Mapped_Count Count (scope: taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Mapped)
# TYPE flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Mapped_Count gauge
flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Mapped_Count{host="172_26_129_190",tm_id="172_26_129_190:6122_3b582c",} 0.0
# HELP flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Heap_Committed Committed (scope: taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Heap)
# TYPE flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Heap_Committed gauge
flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Heap_Committed{host="172_26_129_190",tm_id="172_26_129_190:6122_3b582c",} 4.429185024E9
# HELP flink_taskmanager_Status_Network_AvailableMemorySegments AvailableMemorySegments (scope: taskmanager_Status_Network)
# TYPE flink_taskmanager_Status_Network_AvailableMemorySegments gauge
flink_taskmanager_Status_Network_AvailableMemorySegments{host="172_26_129_190",tm_id="172_26_129_190:6122_3b582c",} 30037.0
# HELP flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Mapped_TotalCapacity TotalCapacity (scope: taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Mapped)
# TYPE flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Mapped_TotalCapacity gauge
flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_Memory_Mapped_TotalCapacity{host="172_26_129_190",tm_id="172_26_129_190:6122_3b582c",} 0.0
# HELP flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_GarbageCollector_G1_Old_Generation_Count Count (scope: taskmanager_Status_JVM_GarbageCollector_G1_Old_Generation)
# TYPE flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_GarbageCollector_G1_Old_Generation_Count gauge
flink_taskmanager_Status_JVM_GarbageCollector_G1_Old_Generation_Count{host="172_26_129_190",tm_id="172_26_129_190:6122_3b582c",} 0.0
```

**Note:** No explicit filter/exclusion configured in the config file.
Can anybody please help how can we get the **taskmanager.job.*** metrics including custom metrics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the flink version. I was using 1.15.0 which has a reported bug on metrics https://lists.apache.org/thread/6bd9vmcroh7576d7h1kdcd8czf0b4l73

Basically, when a job runs, taskmanager metrics related to **taskmanager.job.*** disappears. After upgrading flink to 1.15.2, it started working properly. All the metrics along with custom metrics are getting exported properly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share more of the custom metric code you've used, so we can see it more in context? What you've shared so far isn't obviously correct. Or the problem could be related to the metric name -- how are you looking for it in Prometheus?

You'll find a working example of a custom metric in https://docs.immerok.cloud/docs/how-to-guides/development/measuring-latency/.

Note: I work for Immerok.

Update:

It sounds like the problem is probably on the Prometheus side of things.

A couple of things to check:

1. I assume you have a line in the config that says `metrics.reporters: prom`, but didn't share it above.
2. Make sure you haven't configured Flink to exclude some metrics from being sent to Prometheus. (If the config you shared above is complete, then this isn't the problem.)
3. Check the Prometheus configuration to see which metrics it is scraping (and how often).

https://flink.apache.org/features/2019/03/11/prometheus-monitoring.html is a bit dated, but still relevant.

Note: While this isn't the problem, configuring metrics reporters via their class, as with `metrics.reporter.prom.class`, has been obsolete for a long time and was deprecated in Flink 1.16. This will be removed in 1.17. This line can be updated to

```yaml
metrics.reporter.prom.factory.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusReporterFactory
```

Comment: So far, I am creating only one for testing. Let me update the code. The metric is showing up in the flink UI and getting updated properly.

Comment: Any metrics with this path: flink_taskmanager_job_task_operator_* is not coming up i.e. the metrics name is visible but no value is showing. My custom metric name is also coming up in the list flink_taskmanager_job_task_operator_abc_streamcounter but no value. Am I missing any config!!

Comment: I've updated my answer. If this doesn't help, please share more details of your configuration.

Comment: Thanks David.. I am not using anything to exclude or filter any metrics. Currently, I am checking with the team responsible for scraping the metrics from K8s env. I will share my findings..

Comment: Do we need separate port for jobmanager and taskmanager to expose the metrics!! When we mention metrics.reporter.prom.port: 8080, does it mean both jobmanager and taskmanagers will expose the metrics to port 8080. When I get into jobmanager pod and curl localhost:8080/metrics endpoint, I see bunch of jobmanager metrics. But if I get into taskmanager pod and curl localhost:8080/metrics endpoint, it gives curl: (52) Empty reply from server. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: What I am seeing that all the metrics with taskmanager_Status scope is exposed only. I am able to see that by doing a curl to the metrics endpoint. But what about other scope like taskmanager_job_task. Those are not showing. How do we enable that..

Comment: I edited the question. Can you please take a look @David Anderson..